# Rounding the marker sizes to a given list of ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have marker sizes varied based on a column in my geodataframe but I want the sizes in 5 groups. I don't want every value to have its own size, instead I'd like a range of values to have one marker size.

Here is the code:

```
fig, ax = mpl.pyplot.subplots(1, figsize = (10,10))

sns.scatterplot(
    data=fishpts_clip, x="Lon", y="Lat", color='Green', size='SpeciesCatch',
    sizes=(100, 300), legend="full"
)

plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.5), ncol=1, title='Sizes')
```

This is what I got:

[image]

Instead, I'd like something like this:

[image]

Comment: Your question is interesting, but giving an answer would be like shooting in the dark. In particular, your legend is a bit unusual and one wonders what code produced it. Would you plese [edit] your question, including the matplotlib code that you have used (copy&paste, no screenshot, if possible). Tia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an extra column with each of the values rounded up to one of the desired bounds.  That new column can be used for the `sizes` and the `hue`.  To update the legend, the values are located in the list of bounds; the value itself and the previous one form the new legend label.

The following code illustrates the concept from simplified test data.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.arange(1, 61),
                   'x': np.arange(60) % 10,
                   'y': np.arange(60) // 10 * 10})

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(16, 5))

sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue='val', palette='flare',
                size='val', sizes=(100, 300), legend='full', ax=ax1)
sns.move_legend(ax1, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.5), ncol=6, title='Sizes')
ax1.set_title('using the given values')

# create an extra column with the values rounded up towards one of the bounds
bounds = [0, 5, 10, 20, 40, 60]
round_to_bound = interpolate.interp1d(bounds, bounds, kind='next', fill_value='extrapolate', bounds_error=False)
df['rounded'] = round_to_bound(df['val']).astype(int)

sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue='rounded', palette='flare',
                size='rounded', sizes=(100, 300), ax=ax2)
sns.move_legend(ax2, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.5), ncol=1, title='Sizes')
for t in ax2.legend_.texts:
     v = int(t.get_text())
     t.set_text(f"{bounds[bounds.index(v) - 1]} - {v}")
ax2.set_title('rounding up the values towards given bounds')
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.scatterplot with list of sizes]

Combining a seaborn legend with other elements can be complicated, depending on the situation.  If you just add a pandas plot on top of the seaborn scatter plot, it seems to work out well.  In this case, pandas adds a new element to the existing legend, which can be moved via `sns.move_legend()` at the end.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.arange(1, 61),
                   'x': np.arange(60) % 10,
                   'y': np.arange(60) // 10 * 10})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 5))

# create an extra column with the values rounded up towards one of the bounds
bounds = [0, 5, 10, 20, 40, 60]
round_to_bound = interpolate.interp1d(bounds, bounds, kind='next', fill_value='extrapolate', bounds_error=False)
df['rounded'] = round_to_bound(df['val']).astype(int)

sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue='rounded', palette='flare',
                size='rounded', sizes=(100, 300), ax=ax)
for t in ax.legend_.texts:
    v = int(t.get_text())
    t.set_text(f"{bounds[bounds.index(v) - 1]} - {v}")

# add a pandas plot on top, which extends the legend
xs = np.linspace(0, 9, 200)
ys = np.random.randn(len(xs)).cumsum() * 2 + 25
dams_clip = pd.DataFrame({'dams_ys': ys}, index=xs)
dams_clip.plot(ax=ax, color="Red", linewidth=0.5, markersize=150, zorder=3)
sns.move_legend(ax, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.5), ncol=1, title='Sizes')

sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: extending the legend]

Comment: It worked @JohanC, thank you again. How can I adjust the colors? I want it to be a single color

Comment: You already did that in your example: `color='green'`instead of `palette='flare'`. You'll also need to remove `hue=...`.

Comment: Thank you @JohanC. Sorry for bothering you, but do you have any idea on how to make the legend markers the same color as the color used in the map? Using your example and changing the marker color to green only changed the color on the map while the legend is just black

Comment: It seems seaborn always colors the legend items for `size` as black.  A workaround could be `for h in ax2.legend_.legendHandles:  h.set_color('green')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohanC..it worked

Comment: Please I have one more question @JohanC. I made other plots in my map, eg: `l3 = dams_clip.plot(ax=ax, color="Red", edgecolor='Black', linewidth=0.5, markersize=150, zorder=3)` but I can't figure out how to make the plot legend display alongside with the `seaborn.move_legend` from your example above. Do you know how I can add other plots to the legend?